# How can I use Firebird's Execute Block with Delphi TSQLQuery?

Tags: delphi, parameters, firebird, dbexpress

Using dbExpress TSQLQuery, I can't execute a query with execute block command because that command requires `?` notation for parameters, and Delphi uses `:` for parameters, then, if in the body of that block creates variables and uses them as

```
select data from table where .... into :var;
```

that ":var" is interpreted as a parameter by TSQLQuery.

Which is the way for executing an execute block statement with Delphi?

If I write:

```
execute block(param1 char(1)=:param1)
```

I can load a value for :param1 from Delphi, but when I execute it with `Query.Open` or `Query.ExecSQL` an error returns indicating absence of parameter so ? because in Firebird execute block is written:

```
execute block(param1 char(1)=?param1)
```

Is there any way to resolve this with TSQLQuery?

Comment: @MartynA That question seems unrelated to this problem.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel:  My mistake - somewhere recently I've seem something written about this problem, I thought it was the page I quoted but apparently not.

Answer (score 1):

first you can disable the TSQLQuery property for

```
ParamCheck := False;
```

Then at the beginning of execute block, remove the parameter path..

```
execute block (param1 char (1) = :param1)
```

and your query is passed `(%s)` instead of `:param1.`

I did so in my problem and solved it !

Answer (score 0):

> ":var" is interpreted as a parameter by TSQLQuery

You can turn that off by setting the [`ParamCheck`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.SqlExpr.TCustomSQLDataSet.ParamCheck) property to False.

Comment: ParamCheck is false.
if I use execute block (Use_Code char(1)=:Use_Code, plus char(2)= :plus, fromclass int =:fromclass, f1 timestamp=:f1, f2 timestamp =:f2, prov int =:prov)
returns (texto varchar(4096))    as
declare variable nom varchar(50);
declare variable sucu integer;
begin
  select something from some where prov = :prov into :nom;
  select another from anothertable where class = :fromclass and datecolumn between :f1 and :f2 into :sucu;
end
When Query1.Open or ExecSQL:
Raises exception class TBXError with message 'Token unknown,line x column y ?'.

Comment: @NizamUlMulk that kind of information belongs in your question, not in a comment. Please edit your question

Answer (score 0):

the only way that worked for me was not putting ":" for internal vars in the block.
Ex. `select data from table into var;` and that's work!, then, as this is a block, evaluate the var with an if!

```
if (var = 1)
  do something; 
else
  do anotherthing;
```

and resolved business!

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had a similar issue, but using `FDQuery` (Firedac), the solution found was to set the property, `ResourceOptions.PreprocessCmdText` of `TFQUery` to "False".
Eg.:

```
qryAux.ResourceOptions.PreprocessCmdText := False;
```